# Upload Form Input resets if error message

Tags: forms, upload

Is there a way to preserve the uploaded file with a input upload value if a server side error happens?

What is happening now is when the form submits it throws the error and the uploaded image that we were trying to process clears out and i have to re-attach it each time.

Is there a way to keep it stored in the form data?

Trying to not store a temp file on my server due to the space constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can set the value of an upload field, the user has to select the file each time for security reasons. If you were able to choose what file should be selected via a script it would mean you could potentially force the user to submit sensitive information.

Comment: Yah this is what i thought just wanted to see if there was another way. Thanks for the response